# My quicksort procedure doesn't seem to be doing anything

Tags: pascal, quicksort, procedure

I tried converting my c++ code to Pascal and i'm certain that my code is working. After conversion, everything went well except that the result is NOT the same as to my c++ code to be straight-it doesn't sort anything unlike in c++.
Here is my Pascal:

```
program try_quicksorting;

uses crt;

  var
num: array[1..20] of integer;
x, y, a: integer;
again: char;


procedure quickSort(arr: array of integer; left, right:integer);

var
    i:integer; {pointer for my left side}
    j:integer; {pointer for my right side}
    tmp:integer;
    pivot:integer;
begin

i:=left;
j:=right;

  pivot := arr[(left + right) div 2];

      while (i <= j) do
        begin
        while (arr[i] < pivot) and (arr[j] < pivot) do
        i:=i+1; 
    while (arr[j] > pivot) and (arr[i] > pivot) do
        j:=j-1;

     if(i <= j) then
    begin

            tmp:=arr[i];
                    arr[i]:=arr[j];
                    arr[j]:=tmp;
                    i:=i+1;
                    j:=j-1;

    end;

        end;

 if j > left then
   quickSort(arr, left, j);
if i < right then
   quickSort(arr, i, right);


 end;
 begin

    clrscr;
x:=1;
repeat
    clrscr;


    writeln('******************************************************');
    write('Records: ');

    a:=1;
    while(a<x) do
            begin
     write( num[a], ' ');
    a:=a+1;
    end;

    writeln('');
    writeln('******************************************************');
    write('Enter a number: ');
        readln(num[x]);
    writeln('------------------------------------------------------');


repeat
    write('Again[Y/N]: ');
                read(again);

           if(again = 'y') or (again = 'Y') or (again = 'n') or (again = 'N')then
        x:=x+1
           else
               writeln('Invalid input! Please press Y for Yes and N for No.');

 until (again = 'y') or (again = 'Y') or (again = 'n') or (again = 'N');

 until (again = 'n') or (again = 'N');
 readln;


quickSort(num,1,x);

write('Sorted Form: ');
y:=1;
while (y<x) do
    begin
        write(num[y], ' ');
        y:=y+1;
    end;
    readln;
end.
```

That's it. I'm hoping for your immediate and kind response :)

Comment: use "doesn't" or "does not" instead of "doesnt"; use "I'm" or "I am" instead of "im"; use "immediate" instead of "immidiate".

Comment: Well sorry about that, are u a grammar Nazi? Anyway do you have any answers regarding my question? o.O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In run-of-the-mill Pascal, arrays are value types, so in this

```
procedure quickSort(arr: array of integer; left, right:integer);
```

you are passing a copy of the array.

Change to this

```
procedure quickSort(var arr: array of integer; left, right:integer);
```

and it should work better.